# Is it possible to "add" a rotary fifth valve to a 4-valved tuba?

Tags: instruments, maintenance, brass, tuba, valves

I am currently playing Wessex TB 692 Grand, which is 4-valved BBb tuba.

I have always cherished a 5-valved BBb, so I wonder if it is possible to add a rotary 5th valve to my Wessex horn..

Is this something that would require I find a technician?

Comment: What happened to the 5-valved instrument you cherished?

Comment: Since you're in the UK, why not contact Wessex Tubas Ltd directly?  Or exchange your Grand model to a similarly spec'd [Prokofiev model](https://www.wessex-tubas.com/products/bbb-6-4-tuba-with-5-valves-prokofiev-tb693) which has 5 valves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. But it is quite unusual.

An instrument builder can change your instrument basically any way you wish to. It includes loosening the solders between different tube parts, purchasing and installing the fifth valve, making new tube parts and resolder it together and refinishing the lacquer. Not for the faint hearted and not going to be inexpensive.

My guess is that you will be better off financially buying another instrument instead. But as they say in car adverts, YMMV.